# Using connect-assets with Express to precompile Handlebar templates

Tags: ember.js, express, handlebars.js, connect-assets

I'm using Express, [connect-assets](https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets) on an Ember project. I'm stuck with making `connect-assets` to properly precompile the handlebar templates.

I've configured express like this:

```
app.use(assets({
  src: app_root + 'app',
  buildDir: './public',
  jsCompilers: {
    hbs: hbsAssets
  }
}));
```

and with `hbsAssets` being:

```
module.exports = {
  match: /\.js$/,
  compileSync: function(sourcePath, source) {
    var match = sourcePath.match(/^.*\/app\/js\/templates\/(.+)\.hbs/)
    , templateName = match[1];

    var filename = path.basename(sourcePath, '.hbs')
    , js = handlebars.precompile(source).toString();

    return 'Ember.TEMPLATES' + '["' + templateName + '"] = Handlebars.template(' + js + ');';
  }
};
```

The problem is that the only the hbs layouts get rendered, the `{{outlet}}`s don't get inserted.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the end I ended up using https://npmjs.org/package/ember-template-compiler . It worked out of the box.